# I want to store the session value in search box of appTables using jquery

Tags: php, html, jquery, css, ajax

I want to store the session value in search box of appTables using jquery

```
<?php $session = \Config\Services::session(); ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var searchVals = "<?php echo $session->get('search_by_val'); ?>"; 
        $("#lead-table").appTable({
            source: '<?php echo_uri("leads/list_data") ?>',
            serverSide: true,
            bStateSave: true,
            additionalData: { search_value: searchVals }
         });
     });
</script>
```

In this searchVals variables should pass into additionalData method and when it reloads it should work as per the search parameters.

Comment: **I want to** is not a question. It just informs us that you want us to do the heavy lifting for you.
Where are you stuck? What have you researched? What have you tried? To be clear, we'll help you at stackoverflow but we're not a free do-my-thinking service 
See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: What's wrong with the code you've written? It looks like it should work unless the session value contains double quotes. To protect against that, use `var searchVals = <?php echo json_encode($session->get('search_by_val'); ?>;`

Answer (score 0):

you need to add an event handler for the search box input, so that whenever the user types or changes the search value, it updates the session variable and reloads the appTable.

```
<?php $session = \Config\Services::session(); ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // Function to reload appTable with the updated search value
        function reloadTable() {
            var searchVals = "<?php echo $session->get('search_by_val'); ?>";
            $("#lead-table").appTable({
                source: '<?php echo_uri("leads/list_data") ?>',
                serverSide: true,
                bStateSave: true,
                additionalData: { search_value: searchVals }
            });
        }

        // Get the initial search value from the session and reload the table
        reloadTable();

        // Add an event handler for the search box
        $("#search-box").on('input', function () {
            var searchValue = $(this).val();
            // Update the session variable with the new search value using AJAX
            $.ajax({
                url: '<?php echo_uri("your/update/session/endpoint") ?>',
                method: 'POST',
                data: { search_by_val: searchValue },
                success: function () {
                    // Reload the appTable with the updated search value
                    reloadTable();
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I tried it but itsn't loading the datatables with search tag